# How to push sources to the correct application using remote CLI ?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, command-line-interface

How to remotely manage different applications with PhoneGap CLI ?

In particular, having multiple applications created in the phonegap build apps dashboard, how can I select the correct app to update when using the command `phonegap remote run android` ?

For now I guessed that the application dotted ID (ext.domain.sub.app) will automatically route the sources to the correct app in dashboard, but when I tested to do it, my first app with different ID and Name was overridden!

How to fix that ? 
Have I to give the CLI up simply because I deal with two or more applications ?

My StackOverFlow score doesn't allow me to create the new tag `PhoneGap-CLI`, however it will be usefull, didn't ? Is there a super-hero to create it ?

Comment: You should be creating a separate project on your machine for each app. then browse to which ever one you want to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, indeed, creating a separate project cause automatic separate app in phonegap build.

In fact, in each cordova-cli/phonegap-cli created project, there is a .cordova hidden folder containing a `config.json` file which looks like this :

```
{
    "lib": {
        "www": {
            "id": "ext.domain.sub.appname",
            "version": "1.0.0"
        }
    },
}
```

If the project is sync with phonegap build via phonegap remote run android for example, the cli add this property to the JSON object :

```
    "phonegap": {
        "id": <%= PHONEGAP_BUILD_APP_ID-INT %>
    },
```

In my case, I use custom scripts to deploy several versions of a project which I want to maintain in the same time, in different phonegap build ids.

Then the solution is to "templatize" this JSON file with the wanted ID in my build scripts to run the correct app in the cloud with phonegap when I finally run `phonegap remote run android`.